# Using button on different workbook to generate report, then copying data into workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file made by a different company (so I can't look under the hood so to speak) that pulls data from a server. I can select a date range and then press a button to generate many reports. What I am working on is an excel file to automate selecting a date range and then executing the report. Afterwards copy and paste the information over. Repeated month by month for 10 years. I have the macro working but the screen flickering with my method is making me ill.

The only way I have gotten this to work is by activating the sheet with the button object (not ActiveX button). This is the code I am using where wb_dat is the workbook with the data report, ws_dat0 is the worksheet with the button. This feels like a bad method regardless.

```
'Run the report
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
wb_dat.Activate
ws_dat0.Activate
Application.Run ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

What doesn't work, but I feel like it should is the following

```
Application.Run wb_dat.ws_dat0.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction 'Object Error
Application.Run "excelreport.xlsb!macroname" 'Required worksheet configuration is not defined
```

What happens right now is the worksheet with the button is activated, the report macro runs, everything is good right now. After the report is generated, I use `range.copy` and then `range.pastespecial xlpastevalues`. I feel like this is where the flickering is happening and I can't think about how to prevent it. If I can get the report to run without activating the workbook, I think it would prevent the flickering because testing the macro without generating a new report works fine.

Additional Requested Information (excluding arrays and values for copy/paste):

```
'wb_imp is workbook to have information copied to
Dim wb_imp As Workbook
'wb_dat is workbook to have information generated
Dim wb_dat As Workbook

Set wb_imp = Workbooks("Extract_From_Month_End_Report.xlsm")
Set wb_dat = Workbooks("Month_End_Report.xlsb")


'ws_impi is newly created worksheet for each loop (hence the i)
Dim ws_impi As Worksheet

'ws_imp0 is worksheet with list of date ranges to pull from
Dim ws_imp0 As Worksheet
Set ws_imp0 = wb_imp.Worksheets("Index")

'ws_dat0 is worksheet with date range selection and button to run report
Dim ws_dat0 As Worksheet
Set ws_dat0 = wb_dat.Worksheets("DateSelection")

For i = 2 To 127

    'Sets date range to row i in index
    ws_dat0.Range("E11").FormulaR1C1 = ws_imp0.Cells(i, 1).Value
    ws_dat0.Range("K11").FormulaR1C1 = ws_imp0.Cells(i, 2).Value

    'Run the report
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wb_dat.Activate
    ws_dat0.Activate
    Application.Run ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create new worksheet with date for name
    Set ws_impi = wb_imp.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb_imp.Worksheets(wb_imp.Worksheets.Count))
     d = ws_imp0.Cells(i, 1).Value
     s = CStr(Format(d, "mmm_yyyy"))
     ws_impi.Name = s

    'More loops here to run through array 
    c = 1
    For j = 0 To ArrayL(dat_a) - 1
        ws_impi.Cells(1, c) = dat_a(j).Name
        For k = 0 To ArrayL(dat_n(j)) - 1
            ws_impi.Cells(2, c) = dat_n(j)(k)
            dat_a(j).Range(dat_a(j).Cells(dat_l(j), dat_c(j)(k)), dat_a(j).Cells(dat_u(j), dat_c(j)(k))).Copy
            ws_impi.Range(ws_impi.Cells(3, c), ws_impi.Cells(3 + dat_u(j) - dat_l(j), c)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            c = c + 1
        Next k
        c = c + 1
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Really need to see the rest of your code, including the variable declarations.  `Application.Run ws_dat0.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction` would be more likely to work

Comment: "Required worksheet configuration is not defined" sounds like it might be a message from the workbook you're trying to automate, and perhaps that code makes some assumptions involving the ActiveSheet (possibly it's assumed to be the sheet with the button) which may cause problems if the required sheet is not active.

Comment: I have added more code to the end of my initial question, if that will help

Comment: What if you turn off screenupdating and just leave it off until you're done?

Comment: Turning off screen updating does get rid of the flickering, but it still jumps back and forth between workbooks. It also runs much slower and when each loop takes ~30 seconds to do, it is a slow process

Comment: Also the `Application.Run ws_dat0.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction` stills gets the same error

Comment: Which same error ?  There were two different errors I thought.  also, it's not clear what happens immediately after you "click the button" - where does the output of the process appear/  In a new worksheet/workbook or ?  wht do you need to repeat `wb_dat.Activate` ?  Is there something which is activating another workbook?

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified. For `Application.Run ws_dat0.Shapes("Button 1").OnAction` the exact error is  "Run-time error '438': Required Worksheet Configurationis Not defined in Excel workbook Extract_From_Month_End_Report.xlsm" with the typo as written. When the report is run it calls some SQL

Comment: When you get that error what's the ActiveSheet ?

Comment: I am still on the starting worksheet "ws_imp0", the index page on the workbook i would like to copy information to

Comment: So that specific error only happens when you call the macro when the sheet with the button is not active?  Seems like you're stuck with that if you can't modify the underlying code.

Comment: that is what I am thinking as well. I appreciate you putting in the effort to help me